# Is there a function available with beautifulsoup that will delete all the whitespaces

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am pretty new to Python.
I am trying to scrape the website = https://nl.soccerway.com/.
For this scraping i use beautifulsoup.

The only problem is when I scrape the team names, the team names get 
extracted with whitespace surrounding them on the left and right.

How can I delete this? I know many people asked this question before, but 
I cannot get it to work.

2nd Question:
How can I extract an HREF title out of a TD?
See provided HTML Code.
The club name is Perugia.

- search google
- search stackoverflow

[Perugia](/teams/italy/perugia-calcio/1262/)

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


def main():
    url = 'https://nl.soccerway.com/'
    get_detail_data(get_page(url))

def get_page(url):
    response = requests.get(url)

    if not response.ok:
        print('response code is:', response.status_code)

    else:
        soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'lxml')

    return soup


def get_detail_data(soup):

    minutes = ""
    score  = ""
    TeamA  = ""
    TeamB  = ""

    table_data = soup.find('table',class_='table-container')


    try:
        for tr in table_data.find_all('td', class_='minute visible'):
            minutes = (tr.text)
            print(minutes)
    except:
        pass

    try:
        for tr in soup.find_all('td', class_='team team-a'):
            TeamA = tr.text
            print(TeamA)



    except:
        pass

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use [get_text(strip=True)](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#get-text) method from beautifoulsoup

```
tr.get_text(strip=True)
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the `strip()` method to remove trailing and leading whitespace. So in your case, it would be:

```
TeamA = tr.text.strip()
```

To get the `href` attribute, use the pattern `tag['attribute']`. In your case, it would be:

```
href = tr.a['href']
```